# How to prove the formula for the are a portion of a circle.

Tags: trigonometry

Consider the circle of radius r pictured below with central angle , measured in radians, and subtended arc of length s. Prove that the area of the shaded sector is A = $\frac{1}{2}$$r^2$$\theta$.

[image]

Let's say the entire circle has area B = $\pi$$r^2$.
Using proportionality arguments, the area of a portion of a circle is then $\frac{\theta}{2\pi}$B = $\frac{\theta}{2\pi}$$\pi$$r^2$ which reduces to A = $\frac{1}{2}$$r^2$$\theta$.

Is that right? It seems too easy for a prove. I got this question from a online book which doesn't contain the answer, so I can only resort to stack exchange.

Comment: That will do it.

Answer (score 2):

$A=\int \int dxdy$ ?

Let us use polar coordinates.

$x=rcos(t)$  and $y=rsin(t)$

The Jacobian is $rdrdt$.

thus

$A=\int_0^\theta \int_0^R rdrdt$

$=\theta \frac{R^2}{2}$.